# Keras model.predict() returning same prediction output for all values in test inputs

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

I am using Keras to build a neural net and the model compiles successfully and I have normalized the data.

however, when I use model.predict(xtest) I get the same value for each predicted output

```
def model_final():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu',
                           input_shape=(xtrain.shape[1],),
                          kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.001)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu',
                          kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(0.001)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
    return model

model = model_final()

model_final = model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs = 100, batch_size = 10, verbose = 0)

model_final_eval = model.evaluate(xtest, ytest)
```

for which I get the following mean squared error and mae:

```
214/214 [==============================] - 3s 14ms/step
[1.9285373412534785e-06, 0.00061284683733987052]
```

Then, when I use `model.predict(xtest)` i get the following output:

```
array([[ 0.0014801],
       [ 0.0014801],
       [ 0.0014801],...
```

for all values in the `model.predict`.

I am assuming that the exact same predicted value across all values in the data set cannot be correct.

suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that the input's are all not same?

Comment: Is your data weighted towards that value, i.e does your test data contain mainly 0 values and only a small amount of non zero values, even normalising the data won't reduce a bias towards sampling. 

e.g. if you had 100k datapoints 99k of which were 0 and 1k were non-zero you can achieve 99% accuracy by predicting 0

Comment: @Kalyan - Yes, all the inputs are different

Comment: @ExpiredData - there are actually no zero values because I imputed missing values. Its a relatively small data set (approx 900 total records).

Comment: check if its the same model that was trained on .
Even I had the same issue. In my model.py file, i had elu activation while training and while predicting i was using relu as activation which caused the phenomena to occur .
So while predicting check if all the layers match with training model layers.

Comment: Were you able to solve it ?

Comment: I'm having same issue. How did you solve it???